# VIM: Searching for text in fold titles without automatically opening folds

Tags: vim, gvim

In many cases it would be useful to search for text only in the currently visible fold titles, instead of having Vim automatically opening lots of different folds along the way.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of a way to only search in the fold text (which is usually just the first line of the fold, plus a little extra information), but you can control what actions open folds by setting the `'foldopen'` option.  For example:

```
:set foldopen-=search
```

See "`:help 'foldopen'`" (the single quotes are meant to be typed).